# Magento 2 : The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

There is an issue with the checkout page. On the checkout page, when i fill the shipping address then select the shipping method and click on the next button it redirect to the payment page. But when i check in the database **quote_address** table i can see shipping method value is NULL, i can not see the selected shipping method. This issue is happening only some time. So, i can not track the exact issue.

and i back to the shipping step and select the shipping method again, then my shipping method saves into the database.
Please check this video for the more idea.

https://watch.screencastify.com/v/bimyevlOTA80yoRy01Sp

Please help me to come out. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your video - shipping method is set properly on shiping step and it's available in totals on payment step. I suggest to monitor address state after you've click continue on shipping step, after you click to payment method, after you click to place button.

Answer (score 0):

Make plugin

```
public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
) {
    try {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $selectedShipping = $extAttributes->getSelectedShipping();
        $logger->info(get_class_methods(get_class($extAttributes)));
        $multiCustomship = $extAttributes->getMultiCustomship();
        $this->logger->info("selected shipping ");
        $this->logger->info($extAttributes->getSelectedShipping());
        $this->_coreSession->setSelectedAmount(10); //set total shipping amount
        $this->_coreSession->setSelectedMethods($this->jsonSerializer->unserialize($selectedShipping));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->info('beforeSaveAddressInformation : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
```